# Facebook button slowing down the page

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, plugins, blogger

with the facebook button

[image]

When I remove the button

[image]

The button code below the post-header-line-1 tag

```
<iframe allowTransparency='true' expr:src='&quot;https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot;+ data:post.url + &quot;&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&quot;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:21px;'/>
```

My site is made on google Blogger

Is there how accelerates this code postponing it?

Is there another code that does the same as it for sharing but is fast?

Comment: [This one seems to be very clever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23310867/295783)

Comment: I already tried it

Comment: So why not tell us? Sounds like the perfect solution

Comment: It didn't work, pagespeed still shows a slowness

Comment: as the button is at the beginning of the page. this further hinders loading

Comment: Not at all since it is just 3 links

Comment: was trying this here but the button doesn't appear in place  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060289/social-media-buttons-slow-down-website-load-time

Comment: This one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23310867/295783

Comment: I found this here https://sharingbuttons.io/

Very useful and light, I will use.